# How to customize column name using DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using code below

```
dataTableOptions = {
  "serverSide": true,
  "bFilter": true,
  "paginate": true,
  "aoColumns": [{
      "data": "id",
      "visible": "false"
    },
    {
      "data": "createdDate"
    },
    {
      "data": "type"
    },
    {
      "data": function(data) {
        return "test";
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the last piece of code I am calling function for some manipulation and assigning value to data. I am getting the desired result in the UI, but when I click on the Sort column I am getting column as 'function' on filter; instead I want to set some other name like status.

Comment: WHere is the table code in which you are passing this obj ??? Share more code of the table

Comment: Hi @ShashankVivek
Actually i have bootstrap table with 3 visible columns createdDate,type,status .I am able to display data in table but when i am clicking on datagrid for Status column for sorting i am getting 'function' as column name in other columns i am getting as expected createdDate and type. how can i get column name as status when i am clicking on status table header for sorting.
And i have to use function for some manipulation.if i placed status in place of function then its working fine but i need column name as status with this function.